# Write test class for webservice callout in apex class

Tags: apex, unit-test, webservices, bestpractice

I have one apex class in which I am calling one webservice of one of my managed package installed in my org. When I am writing the test class for my apex class, it is throwing the error

> callout not allowed from test method

Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: I think Salesforce needs to support Mocking managed API so that managed packages can be treated as a black box.

Comment: What does you're response look like? What does it look like when you deserilize it?   You would be able to assert your conditions there

Answer (score 2):

**From the documentation**

> By default, test methods don’t support Web service callouts and tests
>   that perform Web service callouts are skipped. To prevent tests from
>   being skipped and to increase code coverage, Apex provides the
>   built-in WebServiceMock interface and the Test.setMock method that you
>   can use to receive fake responses in a test method.

Take a look at the link below and implement the WebServiceMock interface interface for this.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I don't know how to handle the web service that is part of managed package. Because I am calling a web service that is part of a managed package. Is there something that needs to be taken care of from managed package side.

Answer (score 2):

You need to Mock the HTTP response. The official Apex documentation has plenty of examples doing that. A good starting point is [Testing HTTP Callouts](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_testing.htm) .

Answer (score 0):

http://sfdc.arrowpointe.com/2009/05/01/testing-http-callouts/
Here is a beautiful post written by Scott Hemmeter.
I hope it will help you sorting out your problem.

Comment: This approach is outdated. Callouts should be tested by mocking the response.

Comment: Thanks Alexander could you please guide us to a tutorial where we can learn about Callouts testing by mocking the response. Sorry i saw your post now.